# Ubuntu 16.04 not running scripts in /etc/profile.d/

Tags: 16.04, unity, scripts, environment-variables

I have a machine running Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop (running Unity). I was playing around with different desktop environments for `xrdp`, so I installed `xfce4` (`sudo apt install xfce4`) and `mate-desktop` (`sudo apt install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon`).

However, I found that when using these desktop environments, none of the scripts in `/etc/profile.d` were being run for certain users (specifically mine, which was where I was running the experiments). I removed `xrdp`, `xfce4`, and `mate` to hopefully restore the previous behavior, but to no avail.

Is there anywhere in Ubuntu 16 startup that will show me when/where the `/etc/profile.d` scripts are run? How would installing a different desktop effect this?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those files should be sourced by the display manager.

LightDM: `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session`

GDM: `/etc/gdm3/Xsession`

(I don't know how other DMs work in this respect.)

Please note that the script names must end with `.sh`.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything for GDM (not installed), but the config files in `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session` looks no different from a new install of Ubuntu.

Comment: @FarzadF.: Assuming it's LightDM you use, it should work then. Can you please edit your question and provide details about a script file which you think should work but still does not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was completely unrelated to the session manager.

Upon further inspection, I realized that user that had issues with scripts not being sourced had changed their shell from `bash` to `zsh`. `zsh`, for some reason, wasn't sourcing the scripts in `/etc/profile.d`, which explains why it was working for other users and not this user. I switched them back to `bash` and that seems to have solved the issue.

I guess this begs the question, why wouldn't `zsh` run scripts in `/etc/profile.d`?

Comment: `zsh` is an experimental feature in 19.10 as far as I understand. But a question about it would motivated IMO.

Comment: Just found the same. zsh doesnt but gdm3  will process /etc/profile.d